# MYSQL: How can I find records with a date field in a time range of 24 hours always starting from 6am to 6am next day

Tags: mysql

How can I find records with a date field in a time range of 24 hours with time always starting 6am to 5:59am next day.

Something like:

```
select * from events 
where timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP( 06:00:00 AM)
and timestamp < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(05:59:59 AM)
```

Is it possible?

I have 3 events starting from:
6am to 2pm,
2pm to 10pm and 
10pm to 6am

I need to run a report within a 24 hrs time range with the clock starting everyday at 6am until next day 6am. I like the data to reset at 6am for the next cycle

Thanks

Comment: Would you please show some sample input and your expected output based on that sample input?

Comment: 'Within' is a little ambiguous with respect to past, present, and future

Comment: I need to run a report  within a 24 hrs time range with the clock starting everyday at 6am until next day 6am. And I like the data to reset at 6am for the next cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * 
  from events 
 where timestamp between curdate() + interval 6 hour and curdate() + interval 1 day + interval 6 hour;
```

This should get events from 6AM current date to events for next day 6AM.

Comment: I tried your example and I got zero as result. Is it the timestamp that I am using wrong? If I run this example:  " ... where add_timestamp >= unix_timestamp(now() - interval 24 hour))   I get result. What I am missing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from events where
`timestamp` between date_sub(concat(curdate()," 06:00:00"), INTERVAL 1 DAY) and concat(curdate()," 05:59:59")
```

This query will get all events from 6AM yesterday to 5:59 today.